# missing references at debug time

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

hi there i know its most be a silly mistake but i couldn't find it. i add two references to my project by Right click on References and browse them, i simply use component of these Dlls in my program with no problem, auto complete code is work fine for classes of these Dlls. But when i run my program got error like:

```
The type or namespace name 'GlobalizationDateTimePicker' does not exist in the namespace 'GHDiamond.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

for this line in `myform.Designer.cs`:

```
this.DateTimePicker_AZ = new GHDiamond.Windows.Forms.GlobalizationDateTimePicker();
```

References names are: `GHDiamond.dll and GHDiamond.Win.dll`. they are in Object browser too when a add them, but when i Build my project, `GHDiamond.Win` is not there anymore ! any help will be appreciated

Comment: This may be to do with a namespace clashing issue. Try the following: this.DateTimePicker_AZ = new global::GHDiamond.Windows.Forms.GlobalizationDateTimePicker();

Comment: What is your target framework selected in project properties?

Comment: find problem, target framework was set to .Net framework 4.0 client profile. when i change it to just .net framework 4.0, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Reference in the Solution Explorer and go to the property window. Make sure that the property "Copy Local" is set to "True". This causes the dll to be copied to the output directory.

Comment: @hamze: I have no idea why it is read-only. Does it work when you copy the dll to the target directory with windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I have had something similar which was caused by missing dependent dlls. Autocomplete worked until i built then i would get a load of compile errors. make sure there are no other dlls that you need.

Comment: no i don't think so, i use these DLLs in another project before and it works fine in there